# OnClick events starts on leaving the finger

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface

is there a way to trigger onclick events by the on click and not by leaving the finger because the onclick event only triggers when you leave the finger from the button.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are some of the [helper UI](https://github.com/a1ansa1a/Codes-for-Unity-UI-) that I collected a long time ago and I don't remember the source of them
I uploaded it to github now

There is a script name is ( LeanButton )

From which you can choose OnClick or DownClick

Like Image
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `GetMouseButtonDown`. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetMouseButtonDown.html

Or potentially `GetMouseButton`
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetMouseButton.html

Depending if you want your event to happen once on pressed or repeatedly while pressed.

Answer (score 0):

OnClick is triggered on MouseUp after MouseDown on the same object.

You can use PointerDown() that is sent the first time a finger touches the screen or a mouse button is pressed.